# Method 'ThisWorkbook' of object '_Global' failed - Exporting comments from Word to Excel

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am trying to export comments and corresponding text from Word to Excel using [this code](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/795267-export-comments-corresponding-text-ms-word-excel.html). I copied and pasted the code into VBA as such:

```
Option Explicit




Public Sub FindWordComments()
'Requires reference to Microsoft Word v14.0 Object Library


Dim myWord              As Word.Application
Dim myDoc               As Word.Document
Dim thisComment         As Word.Comment

Dim fDialog             As Office.FileDialog
Dim varFile             As Variant

Dim destSheet           As Worksheet
Dim rowToUse            As Integer
Dim colToUse            As Long

Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
Set destSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
colToUse = 1

With fDialog
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Title = "Import Files"
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Word Documents", "*.docx"
    .Filters.Add "Word Macro Documents", "*.docm"
    .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"
End With

If fDialog.Show Then

    For Each varFile In fDialog.SelectedItems

        rowToUse = 2

        Set myWord = New Word.Application
        Set myDoc = myWord.Documents.Open(varFile)

        For Each thisComment In myDoc.Comments

            With thisComment
                destSheet.Cells(rowToUse, colToUse).Value = .Range.Text
                destSheet.Cells(rowToUse, colToUse + 1).Value = .Scope.Text
                destSheet.Columns(2).AutoFit
            End With

            rowToUse = rowToUse + 1

        Next thisComment

        destSheet.Cells(1, colToUse).Value = Left(myDoc.Name, 4)
        'Put name of interview object in cell A1

        destSheet.Cells(1, colToUse + 1).Value = ActiveDocument.Words.Count
        'Put the number of words in cell B1

        Set myDoc = Nothing
        myWord.Quit

        colToUse = colToUse + 2

    Next varFile

End If

End Sub


Public Sub PrintFirstColumnOnActiveSheetToSheetName()


ActiveSheet.Name = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")


End Sub
```

and VBA returns with the error from the title of my post, and highlighting the code:

```
Set destSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
```

Not sure where to go from here, might I add I am an extremely novice coder/VBA user. I just learned now how to create a macro.

Comment: Is the VBA code within Excel?

Comment: No this is within Word, I'd like to export out the comments and what they refer to in the Word doc into an Excel spreadsheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are running code from within Word, you first need to initialize an instance of Excel and then reference to the workbook of choice

So insert the following code in the head of your sub and replace "WorkbookName" with the name of your Workbook. Then replace `ThisWorkbook` in your code with `wb`

```
Dim objExcelApp As Object
Dim wb As Object
Set objExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = objExcelApp.Workbooks("WorkbookName")
```

If the Workbook is closed replace last line with

```
Set wb = objExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:/Folder1/Book1.xlsm")
```

Comment: Outstanding, thank you so much. A couple of things that I had to fix:

In your last line that you put in to your code the directory should read `"C:\Folder1\Book1.xlsx")` where I had to change the slashes to backslashes and the file name to a .xlsx and not .xlsm

Other than that it worked! Except it's not very intuitive (but it's not your fault), it asks me to reopen the Word doc and it doesn't open up the Excel doc automatically. 

Do you by any chance know how to extract the dates/times for when these comments were made by some lines of code that could be added? 

Thank you

Comment: Maybe even another request would be to add in another column for the section that the comment is in? Is this possible? As well as the time/date? Because right now it's just two columns of text: Column A has the comments and Column B has the text it refers to

Comment: @IgnacioCetrangolo The rule on StackOverflow is: one question / Question. If you need to follow-up, ask a new question.

Comment: In general everything is possible. As @CindyMeister said, I would also suggest to open a new question and to ilustrate what you want to achive. As with this question, try it yourself and post your attempts.

Comment: @FloLie

I've attempted some things to be able to use this same format of code for extracting the author of each comment but haven't had luck. I tried following a similar code that I had from another reference that has the Author in there but it uses a different format altogether. I'm going to make a new post about this like you suggested but if you know how to do it it would be great if you could let me know. Thanks.